# Should the identify-this-song tag be used even if it's not a song?

Tags: discussion, tags

Typically speaking, a "song" indicates a musical composition *with words*. There are some exceptions, like when composers title a piece "Song without Words," but by and large it's *technically* incorrect to refer to an instrumental piece as a "song."

So, the question: if someone is asking for an instrumental work to be identified (like [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4753/unidentified-classical-music-from-youtube-video)), should we still use the `identify-this-song` tag? Or is there an alternate tag we should be using?

Comment: Lacking a better alternative, I'd unceremoniously shove all musical works to be identified under [tag:identify-this-song]. It's a good thing you bring it up on meta though.

Answer (score 2):

Your right, there is no proper tag for identifying instrumental work, until now it was implied to be merged with `identify-this-song`.

Maybe we can create a tag synonym with `identify-this-track` that will be more accurate for all kind of instrumental songs, classical pieces etc.